# Should I not have repotted this Guiana Chestnut a few weeks ago? New small leaves emerge, but also more yellow too. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I repotted this plant into a much larger pot, with indoor potting soil around 4 weeks ago. About 1 week after the repotting, I noticed some of the leaves started to yellow. At the same time, some smaller branches (like the one visible in this photo) also started to emerge.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have been quite careful to not over water, and the soil is well balanced (when I do the hand test, only very fine grains of soil clings onto my hand)

Other factors to note:

- average humidity is relatively low, around 30-40%
- average temp is between 65-70F
- no direct sunlight exposure, but ample light does come into the room

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some plants will cast off leaves when they start growing new leaves, especially when they are about to put on a large growth spurt. The idea is, the new leaves will overshadow the old leaves, so they are not required.

Sadly, some plants will cast off leaves when they are about to die.

You will just have to watch and see. Care for the plant the way that worked for it in the recent past. Try not to give it any big shocks for the next little while. The new leaves look healthy as far as I can tell from the picture. So, you may be OK.

Comment: +1 I would say "move it even closer to light" but I don't know what I'm talking about. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I have been noticing some new growths, so the signs are encouraging at the moment. 

Do you think misting helps? I am unsure if the room is too dry (sometimes the humidity gets down to 20%) which may also be affecting it.